# Using nviz module in GRASS through qgis error

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins

I'm an new user to qgis/GRASS and I've run into a problem with the `nviz module`.

In trying to visualise a raster heat map created from vector contours in 3D using the nviz module in GRASS tools in qgis. I received the following error dialogue box:

```
Can't find usable tk.tcl in the following directories:
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/lib/tcl8.5/tk8.5
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.2/etc/lib/tk8.5
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.2/lib/tk8.5
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.2/etc/library
```

I'm running `QGIS 1.7.4 Wroclaw` on Win7 32 bit and GRASS 6.4.2

I looked in these directories and both tcl8.5 and tk8.5 were missing. I did find tcl8.5.11 and tk8.5.11 on sourceforge. I'm now not sure how to proceed. Will these files fix my problem and how do I get them running and into the right directories?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you installed also the tcl/tk libraries through the OSGeo4W installer.